# I need to rearrange cell values according to certain conditions in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I have a spread sheet that looks like this:

| Containers | Contents |
| --- | --- |
| Crate |  |
|  | Apples |
|  | Bananas |
|  | Oranges |
| Barrel |  |
|  | Grapes |
|  | Apples |

Indicating that the crate holds apples, bananas, and oranges, and the barrel grapes and apples. Now a need functions first search output all different containers (they all have distinct names) and then lists their contents as follows:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Crate | Apples | Bananas | Oranges |
| Barrel | Grapes | Apples |  |

A container can hold any number of contents and it would be extra nice if they were arranged in alphabetical order.

Which functions would yield this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of using <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper functions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,SCAN(,A2:A8,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     b,SORT(UNIQUE(a)),
     HSTACK(b,DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",b,LAMBDA(m,n,
     VSTACK(m,SORT(TOROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B8,n=a)),1),,,1)))),""),1)))
```

---